# Where can I get the source code for MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to look into the way bundling is implemented. It seems like there is default bundling as my MVC project knows all about adding in javascripts that I don't have and never explicitly included.

Comment: I believe Microsoft's still not open source this. You can find out in http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/. There is no namespace with name System.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle is simply logical group of files that could be referenced by unique name and being loaded with one HTTP request. Two things that will help you use these new features, are `RegisterTemplateBundles()` and `EnableDefaultBundles()`.

Bundling of scripts is a new feature in MVC 4, to learn more about it take a look at [New in ASP.NET MVC4: Bundling and Minification](http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html) and [Yet Another Bundling Approach for MVC 4](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/20/yet-another-bundling-approach-for-mvc-4.aspx)

The purpose of bundling and minification is to help increase the performance of your Websites by reducing the number and size of HTTP Requests to the server.

If you want code examples you can find walk-troughs and source examples in Visual Studio's Nuget package manager. There are many other sources, comment if you want me to add more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's at: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/